# How to parse tuples that has no delimiters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pyparsing

I'm using pyparser and want to parse files that contain tree structure with values stored after equals sign with no actual delimiters otherwise.

I've done all the parsing so well except for rare cases when data is stored in multiple lines, so I have to rewrite parser not to stop grabbing value as something from equals sign to end of line but from equals sign to another equals sign (or `end`) ignoring the word that preceeds it (or ignoring `end`).

Example of data:

```
(
  ItemName = foo
  SomeOtherStuff = bar
  foo1
  foo2
  AString1 = ItemName
  SomeOtherStuff 
)
```

Code:

```
equals = Suppress("=")
token = Word(alphanums + "-,./_:*+=#[];")
decimal = Regex(r'-?0|[1-9]\d*').setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
stringTemplate = token | decimal
sexpList = Group(Suppress("(") + ZeroOrMore(sexp) + Suppress(")")) 
sexp = Forward()
```

This doesn't work obviously

> astring = Group(stringTemplate + equals + stringTemplate)

So I've tried these:

```
multilineString = Group(token + equals + OneOrMore(stringTemplate) + ~FollowedBy(stringTemplate + equals))
multilineString = Group(token + equals + OneOrMore(stringTemplate) + NotAny(stringTemplate + equals))
multilineString = Group(token + equals + OneOrMore(stringTemplate) + ~(stringTemplate + equals))
```

But it didn't work. What I got were either errors or parser gobbling up all of the data as one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `~FollowedBy`, but these expressions have to be part of the `OneOrMore` repetitive expression. Something like:

```
multilineString = Group(token + equals + OneOrMore(stringTemplate + ~FollowedBy(equals)))
for match in multilineString.searchString(test):
    match.pprint()
```

Some other comments:

- Look at the definitions of `token`, `decimal`, and `stringTemplate`. As it stands now, you will never match the `decimal` expression. To avoid mistaking an `integer` for a `token`, I suggest you change `token` to `Word(alphas, alphanums + "-,./_:*+=#[];")`
- You may want to reconsider whether you want to allow '=' as part of a `token`. If someone omits the space between a `token` and the delimiting '=', what was meant to be a delimiter will get sucked up into the `token` key.
- Consider adding results names to help you access the key and value bits of each key-value pair: `multilineString = Group(token("key") + equals + OneOrMore(stringTemplate + ~FollowedBy(equals))("value"))`. Then you can access them like `match.key` and `match.value` - of course you can just use list indexing to get the key as `match[0]`, but I find the named access easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you. This task and your comment helped greatly with understanding of pyparsing. A great tool indeed.